# XSLT - search and find specific tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible in XSLT to find a specific tag and replace it with its contents? For example, given this XML:

```
<span>Hello world</span>
```

we'd end up with this:

```
Hello world
```

So the useless and redundant SPAN tag is replaced with its contents, at any level (recursively). We'd want to find the "naked" span tags (the ones with no attributes) and replace them with their content.

I'm processing XML over which I don't have control. Thanks.

Update: Here's what the *.XSL file contains, followed by sample output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
  xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:param name="ItemsHaveStreams">
    <xsl:value-of select="'False'" />
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:variable name="OnClickTargetAttribute" select="string('javascript:this.target=&quot;_blank&quot;')" />
  <xsl:variable name="ImageWidth" />
  <xsl:variable name="ImageHeight" />
  <xsl:template name="Contact" match="Row[@Style='Contact']" mode="itemstyle">
      <div class="outer-container">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td class="ms-vb" style="text-align:left; padding:9px;">
            <span style="font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px solid #999;"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></span>

            <!-- Phone and Emergency Phone -->
            <xsl:if test="@Phone != '' or @EmergencyPhone != ''">
              <xsl:if test="@Phone != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Phone" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="@EmergencyPhone != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="@EmergencyPhone" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- Email -->
            <xsl:if test="@Email != ''">
              <span style="text-align:left">E-mail: <a href="mailto:{@Email}"><xsl:value-of select="@Email"/></a></span>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- Address & Map -->
            <!--
              Must test for both empty string and empty div tags, escaped.
            -->
            <xsl:if test="@Address != '' and @Address !='&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;'">
              <p>Address: <xsl:value-of select="@Address" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Map != ''">
              (<a href="{@Map}">MAP</a>)
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- Opening Hours -->
            <xsl:if test="@OpeningHours != ''">
              <p><b>Opening Hours:</b></p>
              <xsl:value-of select="@OpeningHours" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </td>                 
        </tr>
      </table> 
      </div> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's a sample output currently:

```
Contact Health Services

    962-8328
    962-8945 

Emergency only: 962-8884
After hours, contact Security Dispatch to connect with Health Services staff on duty.

E-mail: health@mydomain.org

Address: 
123 Main St.

(MAP)

Opening Hours:
Sunday -Thursday     08:00 -17:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath will find all `span` elements without attributes:

```
//span[not(@*)]
```

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span[not(@*)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kirill. You make it look so easy! Is it possible to do other XSLT to the output of the above? For example, if I need to apply styling, etc. I have a custom template, would that go after the above code (inside the closing stylesheet tag)?

Comment: @Alex, You're welcome. Can you provide sample XML and sample output XML? (Update your question)

Comment: @Alex, Explain more clearly, please. I still don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. Basically, with the changes you suggested, where would the XSLT I already have in my *.XSL file go? Would I put your XSLT at the top, inside the `xsl:stylesheet` tag before my XSLT? I'm a newbie to XSLT so forgive my ignorance please :) Thanks.

Comment: @Alex, Well. My XSLT: 1st template (`match="@* | node()"`) will match any node (element, attribute, etc.) and copy it to output XML. If it finds `span` element without any attribute 2nd template (`span[not(@*)]`) will apply, which doesn't copy element itself.